# SOAP with suds raises TransportError with code 500

Tags: python, soap, suds

I'm trying to use suds package to connect to a web service, but i get TransportError, what am i doing wrong?

```
from suds.client import Client
wsdl_url = 'https://sep.shaparak.ir/payments/referencepayment.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(wsdl_url)
```

This is the error i'm getting:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 67, in open
    return self.u2open(u2request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 132, in u2open
    return url.open(u2request, timeout=tm)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 469, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 579, in http_response
    'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 507, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 441, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\urllib\request.py", line 587, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\client.py", line 115, in __init__
    self.wsdl = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 150, in open
    d = self.fn(url, self.options)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\wsdl.py", line 136, in __init__
    d = reader.open(url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 74, in open
    d = self.download(url)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\reader.py", line 92, in download
    fp = self.options.transport.open(Request(url))
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\https.py", line 62, in open
    return HttpTransport.open(self, request)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\suds\transport\http.py", line 69, in open
    raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error
```

Am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and it solved by using [zeep](https://python-zeep.readthedocs.io) library for soup protocol.
It seems that development of suds library is stopped. So you should switch to this alternative.

After installing zeep you can replace your code with the code bellow, then all is done.

```
from zeep import Client
wsdl_url = 'https://sep.shaparak.ir/payments/referencepayment.asmx?WSDL'
client = Client(wsdl_url)
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94027/285661) for instructions how to write *better* "link-based" answers. Thanks!